# Curl post проверка содержимого

Tags: php, post, curl

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть curl запрос на php.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php

// set post fields
$post = [
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'subaction' => 'dologin'
];
$ch = curl_init('url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);
// do anything you want with your response
if ($response == 'Module mod_rewrite') {
echo 'Пароль подошел';
}
else {
    echo 'Пароль не подошел';
}
echo $response;
?>
```

Содержимое страницы получаем в переменную `$response`.
Как сделать условие если в содержимом странице то есть в переменной `$response` есть определенный текст выводим одно сообщение, если нет то второе.

Comment: тип получаемых данных?

Comment: @ArchDemon содержимое страницы url

Comment: @ArchDemon html

Comment: Берёте библиотеку http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net или аналогичную. И можете искать на странице нужный блок и проверять на нужный текст. Если по очень простому пути, то ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод strpos:

```
if (strpos($response, $needle) !== false) {
  echo "$needle найден в $response";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, закрыто